# Pbox and S-Box values in AUT64

Tags: block-cipher, s-boxes

I am looking to get P-box and S-box from firmware

Decided to search the firmware for

Pbox - 8 nibbles from 0-7

i.e

```
pbox = [2, 0, 6, 5, 7, 4, 3, 1]
```

Found it :)

And for S-Box

16 bytes from 0-15 (based on my research on S-box)

i.e

```
sbox = [5, 11, 7, 12, 4, 8, 0, 3, 13, 9, 6, 1, 2, 14, 10, 15]
```

However cannot find it in firmware.

They should be next to each other in firmware.

But they're not.

Question:

Are my assumptions about pbox values and Sbox values correct? i.e values from 0-7 for pbox and 0-16 for sbox?